# how install glimpse nuget package on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, nuget, glimpse

Package is installed on local machines with a reference to packages folder added in project. Now If I publish it on server, it is causing problem as glimpse is not installed on server. Please guide what is the best way to install it on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glimpse just needs its DLL's to be in the `bin` folder on the server.

Some deployment techniques (like on Azure Websites) leverage [NuGet package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) to download dependencies and build your site right on the server. With these techniques you don't have to do anything.

For simpler techniques, like xcopy or FTP of files, just make sure to include the DLL's - they are already being copied to the `bin` when you build your site.